# PHPMyadmin oauth 2.0 client

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I wanted to implement Oauth client verification for users connecting PHPmyadmin.
Example: When a user wanted to connect to phpmyadmin webpage. He should be verified and then he should come to phpmyadmin database login page.

Has someone implemented it. If So can you please help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of phpMyAdmin's Auth types called signon to achieve it. Visit [here](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types#signon) to get more information.

In **config.inc.php** :

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'signon';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonSession'] = 'SignonSession';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonURL']     = 'examples/signon.php';
?>
```

In **examples/signon.php** :

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['callback'])){
    //TODO: Redirect to OAuth Server to finsh the log in.
    //Do not forget to include callback=1 in your redirect_uri parameter
}else{
    // make the cookie reachable :
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', 0);
    // same as in config.inc.php : 
    session_name('SignonSession');
    session_start();

    //TODO: Get user's mysql username and password
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_user'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_host'] = 1; // If you have more than 1 host in config.inc.php, please specify host here

    // save changes :
    session_write_close();
    // finally redirect to phpMyAdmin :
    header('Location: ../index.php?server=1');
}
```

Hope this can help you.